# How to setup WireGuard client so only traffice for specific IPs is routed over VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, client, wireguard

I am using the Wireguard VPN client on Ubuntu 20.04 through the network-manager plug-in. The plug-in reads the configuration file I got from the sys admin, which is below (network-manager also handles the startup and shutdown of the wg client):

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = removed
Address = 10.200.85.2/32
MTU = 1412
DNS = 10.200.85.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = removed
Endpoint = removed
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

The computers I am trying to reach on the other side of the VPN are in the 10.0.15.xxx range.

This works, except that ALL traffic on my client is routed through the WireGuard VPN. I only want traffic for 10.0.15.xxx routed through the WireGuard VPN.

I have tried changing AllowedIPs to addresses containing various permutations of 10.200.85.x/x and 10.0.15.x/x, It seems that changing AllowedIPs to anything but 0.0.0.0/0 prevents anything from getting routed over the VPN, and "ip route get" shows the route for all addresses going through the primary network connection.

The WireGuard setup in Network Manager also has a "Use this connection only for resources on its network", but checking that with AllowedIps = 0.0.0.0/0 still sends all traffic over the VPN.

I found a post on here [Configuring routes so that vpn is only used for local resources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968464/configuring-routes-so-that-vpn-is-only-used-for-local-resources) showing how to add some routes for a PPP VPN to accomplish what I am trying to do.  It basically assigned a route for the desired remote network to the PPP adapter, and then added a route for 0.0.0.0 with a high metric.  I added routes as suggested in that article to the Network Manager WireGuard setup, but everything is still routed over the WireGuard VPN. I could see that the routes were added with "route -n", but the high WireGuard metric for 0.0.0.0 didn't encourage traffic to be routed over the primary network connection.

Any suggestions on how to send only traffic for 10.x.x.x over the WireGuard VPN? Probably something simple I am missing.  Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Also, it seems odd to me that when the WireGuard VPN is running, there is no route in the route table...

```
jhuber@t5610:~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 34:17:eb:ad:40:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
47: APC-Wireguard: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1412 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/none 

jhuber@t5610:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref       Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s25
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s25
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25

jhuber@t5610:~$ ip route get 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 dev APC-Wireguard table 51820 src 10.200.85.2 uid 1000 
cache
```

Comment: I'm having a slightly similar issue, but I'm much newer to WireGuard. Would it be possible for you to post your config files, without public IPs of course so we can get the benefit of seeing how this is supposed to work? I want my peers to be able to access specific IPs within the VPN tunnel (no outside DNS querries, just internal stuff). I also want traffic to ONLY be routed from a client if it's an internal resource (in the tunnel). Please help if you see this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, there seems to be an issue with the interaction between the network-manager-wireguard plug-in and NetworkManager.  I switched over to the command line with `sudo wg-quick up` with `AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0\8`, and the VPN works as expected.  10.x.x.x traffic is routed through the VPN, and all other traffic goes over the primary network connection.

In comparing the route tables for the two methods, the route below seems to be missing when NetworkManager sets up the WireGurad VPN:

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface`

`10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 APC-Wireguard`

As a work-around, I added this route on the IPV4 tab for the WireGuard setup in NetworkManager, and it seems to solve the problem.  In browsing through the network-manager-wireguard code, although I don't fully understand it, the code seems to adjust the routes created by `wg-quick`, and it may not be doing that properly.

Comment: I'm experiencing this bug (i think), on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Do you have any updates on this bug, like if it is fixed upstream or the bug report is created already?

Comment: I don't know if any improvements have been made, or if a bug report has been made.  I have been successfully using the workaround a noted above, and really haven't looked into the matter further, since the workaround was functioning well for me.